# Why do I need to refresh a token if im using a service account with pydrive?

Tags: python, oauth, google-api, pydrive

I'm using pydrive to upload some files to my drive. I authenticate using the following:

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    settings.GOOGLE_API_SERVICE_ACCOUNT, scopes
)


pydrive_auth = GoogleAuth()
pydrive_auth.credentials = credentials
drive = GoogleDrive(pydrive_auth)
....
```

After a while apparently pydrive tries to refresh an access token and tries to find a `client_secret.json` which is not present on my server and therefore causes it to fail. Why should it be trying to refresh an access token if I'm using a service account? I thought service accounts didnt need tokens. Is there something I'm missing in the code or do I need to add this missing file?

Comment: i would be curios to know how you think its trying to refresh a refresh token.  Whats the errror message?

Comment: Mentions that the access token is expired and then tries to find the clients_secret.json file in order to refresh it

Answer (score 0):

No refresh tokens are not needed with service accounts.

Refresh tokens are granted to you by a user which will give you access to access their data when they are not online.

Service accounts are preauthorized they always have access, in a way they are permanently a refresh token if you want to look at it that way.

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
gauth.credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(JSON_FILE, scope)
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

my_file = drive.CreateFile({'id': 'FILE_ID'})
```

Comment: Then what do I need to change for this to work?

Comment: I cant really tell you remove what ever in your code is trying to refresh an access token, sounds like you have copied another type of client and just replaced the service account auth.   I checked and pydrive appears to support service account authentication .

Comment: The code in your snippet is exactly what I have in my code, nothing more and it still tries to refresh. Im thinking it might be this: https://github.com/googleworkspace/PyDrive/issues/107#issuecomment-685854516